# Rails using REST resource and being able to delete without a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

Rails simulates a DELETE on a resource by using POST and a hidden field in the Form. But that makes it a must to use a form to delete a record.
However if I wanted to delete a row via a Anchor tag 'Delete' displayed at the end of the row how would I achieve the same? So say I am displaying people records and my rows looks like:

||First Name|| Last Name|| 
||Foo       || Bar      ||  Delete 
||Baz       || Foo      ||  Delete 
...

And on the delete click I want to route to /people/:id/destroy without using a Form and Hidden field?

Comment: I know I can add: 
map.connect 'people/:id/destroy',:controller => 'people', :action => 'destroy'

However I wanted to only use the map.resource :people which I already have which works for all except the delete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails' [link_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) method supports the `GET`, `POST`, `PUT`, and `DELETE` HTTP verbs. For example, you could do something like:

```
link_to "Delete", person_path(@person), method: :delete, confirm: "Are you sure?"
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to

Comment: Awesome, works like a charm. Rails adds an onClick event for the href which then sets up the whole form using JS. Nice!

Comment: @Turd But how does this work for browsers with JS turned off? Shouldn't they be able to use the link as well?

Comment: This solution won't work if JS isn't enabled. Links cannot send DELETE requests. When you specify `method: :delete` all it does is add a `data-method` attribute to the link which rails-ujs watches for. If you need a solution that works without js when you would need to use [button_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to) and style the button to look like a link.